# Codification in JSP Imports

Tags: html, jsp, utf-8, character-encoding, include

Good night.

I'm having trouble import static html page to a JSP page with UTF-8.

My JSP is UTF-8. I Write my HTML fragment with UTF-8, but I include with <%@include file="includes/menu.html"%>, the text is with the wrong encoding.

My JSP is complex, but my html is, an simple example:

```
<div>
   <ul>
      <li>Text with Á (acentuation)</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Is very simple html, containing the application menu, but this error is occurring.

A very simple JSP is:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>

    <%@include file="includes/menu.html"%>

</body>
```

PS: if I put directly in JSP, it works normally.

Comment: show us the inluded jsp code

Comment: <%@include file="includes/menu.html"%>

Comment: try adding <% request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8"); %>, before include.

Comment: my jsp include <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to change the `menu.html` to `menu.jsp` and on the top of the new file add

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

and then include this jsp in your page

```
<body>
  <%@include file="includes/menu.jsp"%>
</body>
```

Comment: have it, it was written with UTF-8 encoding (I created it UTF-8, I copied the contents in UTF-8 and pasted it)

Comment: the default encoding in my IDE is UTF-8.

Comment: do you have such a tag in your html or not?

Comment: Not in html, but when I import will not have problems with the insertion?

Comment: no no no, I have all tags in my JSP (write with HTML5), I just want to include that html into it, but the JSP is already configured. html has no body, it is only to be inserted. Get it?

Comment: I have already included this in my JSP: <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

Comment: Works fine man, but I change <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> to <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>, because the conflict. Works now, =]].